# Technique for predicting ratios given earlier observations

Tags: estimation, prediction

Say I have the following situation:

A realtor has previously estimated the values of `n` properties to be `x1, ..., xn`. They sold for `y1, ..., yn`.

Now, what are some possible models/techniques I can read up on for obtaining a sound range for the selling sum of `k` new properties, the realtor has estimated at `z1, ..., zk`?

I am, naïvely thinking, that one could use some estimator on `y/x` and use that value to obtain a confidence interval for the sum of the new k properties, but I haven't seen this type of estimation in my stats course.